# cgo Interacting with C Library that uses Thread Local Storage

Tags: c, multithreading, go, cgo, thread-local-storage

I'm in the midst of wrapping a C library with cgo to be usable by normal Go code.

My problem is that I'd like to propagate error strings up to the Go API, but the C library in question makes error strings available via thread-local storage; there's a global `get_error()` call that returns a pointer to thread local character data.

My original plan was to call into C via cgo, check if the call returned an error, and if so, wrap the error string using `C.GoString` to convert it from a raw character pointer into a Go string. It'd look something like `C.GoString(C.get_error())`.

The problem that I foresee here is that TLS in C works on the level of native OS threads, but in my understanding, the calling Go code will be coming from one of potentially N goroutines that are multiplexed across some number of underlying native threads in a thread pool managed by the Go scheduler.

What I'm afraid of is running into a situation where I call into the C routine, then after the C routine returns, but before I copy the error string, the Go scheduler decides to swap the current goroutine out for another one. When the original goroutine gets swapped back in, it could potentially be on a different native thread for all I know, but even if it gets swapped back onto the same thread, any goroutines that ran there in the intervening time could've changed the state of the TLS, causing me to load an error string for an unrelated call.

My questions are these:

- Is this a reasonable concern? Am I misunderstanding something about the go scheduler, or the way it interacts with cgo, that would cause this to not be an issue?
- If this is a reasonable concern, how can I work around it?

  - cgo somehow manages to propagate errno values back to the calling Go code, which are also stored in TLS, which makes me think there must be a safe way to do this.
  - I can't think of a way that the C code itself could get preempted by the go scheduler, so should I introduce a wrapper C function and have IT make the necessary call and then conditionally copy the error string before returning back up to goland?

I'm interested in any solution that would allow me to propagate the error strings out to the rest of Go, but I'm hoping to avoid any solution that would require me to serialize accesses around the TLS, as adding a lock just to grab an error string seems greatly unfortunate to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'm afraid of is running into a situation where I call into the C routine, then after the C routine returns, but before I copy the error string, the Go scheduler decides to swap the current goroutine out for another one. ...
>
> Is this a reasonable concern?

Yes.  The cgo "call C code" wrappers lock on to one POSIX / OS thread for the duration of each call, but the thread they lock is not fixed for all time; it does in fact [bop around](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/bop), as it were, to multiple different threads over time, as long as your goroutines are operating normally.  (Since Go is cooperatively scheduled in the current implementations, you can, in some circumstances, be careful not to do anything that might let you switch underlying OS threads, but this is probably not a good plan.)

You *can* use [`runtime.LockOSThread`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) here, but I think the best plan is otherwise:

> how can I work around it?

Grab the error *before* Go resumes its normal scheduling algorithm (i.e., before unlocking the goroutine from the C / POSIX thread).

> cgo somehow manages to propagate errno values ...

It grabs the errno value *before* unlocking the goroutine from the POSIX thread.

> My original plan was to call into C via cgo, check if the call returned an error, and if so, wrap the error string using `C.GoString` to convert it from a raw character pointer into a Go string. It'd look something like `C.GoString(C.get_error())`.

If there is a variant of this that takes the error *number* (rather than fishing it out of a TLS variable), that plan should still work: just make sure that your C routines provide both the return value and the error number.

If not, write your own C wrapper, just as you suggested:

```
ftype wrapper_for_realfunc(char **errp, arg1type arg1, arg2type arg2) {
    ftype ret = realfunc(arg1, arg2);
    if IS_ERROR(ret) {
        *errp = get_error();
    } else {
        *errp = NULL;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Now your Go wrapper simply calls the wrapper, which fills in a pointer to C memory with an extra `*C.char` argument, setting it to nil if there is no error, and setting it to something on which you can use `C.GoString` if there is an error.

If that's not feasible for some reason, consider using `runtime.LockOSThread` and its counterpart, [`runtime.UnlockOSThread`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#UnlockOSThread).

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response! Unfortunately the TLS call is the only way the library currently makes the error string available, and there's quite a large number of functions I would need to wrap in this way...

Comment: I would normally be hesitant to go in the LockOSThread direction because I assume it has significant impact on the overall performance of the Go scheduler, but if I'm reading this correctly, cgo _already_ issues a call to LockOSThread on every single C call regardless of anything I do. If this understanding is correct, am I correct in assuming that the additional overhead of calling it before making the C call is unlikely to be significant?

Comment: I haven't seen the cgo implementation specifically, but I'd bet that it does indeed use `runtime.LockOSThread` directly itself. It looks like the overhead should be relatively low. (BTW you might consider autogenerating the wrappers—Go does a lot of "generate some code at compile time" already, as a sort of substitute for generics.)